# Not able to sort data after using skip in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting

This is the Query am using:-

```
 var retrieveQuery = function(callback){
               Product.find(qry).skip((pageNumber-1)*12).sort({sortby: -1}).limit(12).exec(function(err, doc){
                if(err){ callback(err, null) }
                else{
                    callback(null, doc);
                 }
          });
               
          };
```

Here `qry` is  `let qry=JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(req.params.query));`

and am send url as `/p3nhv/%7B %7D/lastEdit/1` which indicates `/:token/:query/:sortby/:page`
Result am getting is unsorted,
**Doubts:**

1. Is it sorting whole data or the only specific dataset which I am retrieving?
2. skipped dataset included in sort?

Here is my mongo data:-

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5a71eb6339add500269e4be1"
},
"editTime": {
    "$date": "2018-01-31T16:14:27.000Z"
},
"userName": "Some Name",
"userId": {
    "$oid": "5a0def6859465800269e9b5e"
},
"city": {
    "$oid": "5a0969adca18d8fd03d57d2c"
},
"college": {
    "$oid": "5a0969adca18d8fd03d57d2c"
},

"lastEdit": {
    "$date": "2018-01-31T16:14:27.605Z"
},
"productDescription": "test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test ",
"pageView": 0,
"time": {
    "$date": "2018-01-31T16:14:27.605Z"
},
"__v": 0
```

}

am sorting by `lastEdit` don't know what mistake I did everything seems fine any help will be great, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sort will occur before the `skip` and `limit` are applied, but you're currently sorting by the (non-existent) field named "sortby" rather than the name of the field *contained* in `sortby`.

Use the computed property syntax instead:

```
.sort({[sortby]: -1})
```

Or use the string-based, alternate sorting syntax supported by Mongoose:

```
.sort('-' + sortby)
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter what order we apply these constraints (skip, sort, limit) to the cursor MongoDB will **always sort first, skip second and limit third** so that is skip limit and sort or should I say sort skip and limit within the node js driver. Therefore, you will ***limiting*** your ***skiped*** dataset, and you will be ***skipping*** your ***ordered*** data set always.

[Here](http://learnwebtutorials.com/using-sort-skip-and-limit-in-mongodb) a really good article about this.

#### So, your Doubts:

> Is it sorting whole data or the only specific dataset which I am retrieving?

A: The whole data

> skipped dataset included in sort?

A: Yes